# How to open pdf, pptx, doc, docx files in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I click on file how to open that file inside flutter app.
This is what I have done:

[image]

This code for show flies in listView:

```
ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: attachments.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                print (index);
                return ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            child: _getIcon(
                                attachments[index].split('/').removeLast()),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          subtitle:
                          Text(attachments[index].split('/').removeLast()),
                          onTap: (){}
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]);
              })
```

I have used open_file package but its not working this is code i have done:

```
            onTap: () async {
            String fileUrl = widget.schoolDcUrl + "/container"attachments[index];
            final _openFile = await OpenFile.open(fileUrl);
             Logger.i(_openFile);
                              }
```

When I click on file it does not opening the file it will give a message on terminal file not found.

I want onTap to open that file in application.

Comment: Open files in the app will require a lot of code to be able to handle all formats, it is strongly recommended to use a dedicated application, you can use: https://pub.dev/packages/open_file

Comment: I have used open_file package but its not working--This is code i have done          
    onTap: () async {
                    String fileUrl = widget.schoolDcUrl + "/container" + attachments[index];
                            String fileUrl1 = Uri.encodeFull(fileUrl);
                            final _openFile = await OpenFile.open(fileUrl);
                          Logger.i(_openFile);
                         }

Comment: this is perfect answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60203399/15601357
without any boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

In `pubspec.yaml` add:

```
dev_dependencies:
   open_file: ^3.0.1
```

In code add:

```
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.pptx");
```

`open_file` documentation:
https://pub.dev/packages/open_file#-readme-tab-

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [flutter_filereader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader) package that opens all of those file formats.

Make sure to follow the configurations and the example on the README.

Comment: my file is coming from api--- String fileUrl = widget.schoolDcUrl + "/container"attachments[index]; this file path can we open this using filereader package

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: this is my file url :String fileUrl = widget.schoolDcUrl + "/container"attachments[index];  now i click on file how to open inside flutter app

Comment: Have you attempted to use the package I linked in my answer?

Comment: Are the files local or remote?

Comment: I'm accessing files which is stored on server

Comment: Then you would have to download them first. I don't know if this package supports opening files remotely.

Comment: When I'm try to open that file on ios it does't work ? It is working for Android but not working for io

Comment: The issue is with the loading title its all in chinese and Im not able to resolve it.Check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661674/change-chinese-title-to-english-using-flutter-filereader-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

without downloading file, you can open from URL using the package : [**url_launcher 5.4.1**](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#-readme-tab-)

```
_launchURL(String url) async {
  const url = url; // you can use your url
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Unable to open url : $url';
  }
}
```