# Change chinese title to english using flutter_filereader in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, filereader

Hope you all doing fine. I want to develop an Flutter application to view all major types of documents which include; .docx, .ppt, .pptx, .doc, .xls, .xlsx, .pdf files I found two free plugin which are file_preview (https://github.com/aliyoge/flutter_file_preview/blob/master/android/src/main/java/zzaning/com/filepreview/LoadFileApi.java) and file_preview (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader) but the issue with these two is they both download some plugin at initial or at very first time when app start's up. Which only shows in log and I am not able to show it on loading screen plus second issue is when a document is loaded it displays in Chinese language which I can not get rid of.

Please help me out guys.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Chinese develop the packages, so the language is mostly in Chinese.

For the issue when a document is loaded, it displays in the Chinese language which you can not get rid of, my solution is you just download the latest packages file inside the version archive menu [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader/versions).

And then, open the file and translate each Chinese language manually using Google Translate.

After you've finished it, you can add that manually to your project.

As for another issue, you can (again) edit the file and display it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940719/how-to-log-data-to-the-flutter-console). I hope it will help a little bit.